# RoundedImageview with border color

Tags: android, imageview

I have following code to make the ImageView circular. How can I implement a border with color? I tried to implent some solutions, also those on Stackoverflow, but without success. Here the current progress:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
        int radius = w < h ? w : h;

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, radius, w, h);
        // roundBitmap= ImageUtils.setCircularInnerGlow(roundBitmap, 0xFFBAB399,
        // 4, 1);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius, int w, int h) {
        Bitmap sbmp;
        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            float _w_rate = 1.0f * radius / bmp.getWidth();
            float _h_rate = 1.0f * radius / bmp.getHeight();
            float _rate = _w_rate < _h_rate ? _h_rate : _w_rate;
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() * _rate), (int)(bmp.getHeight() * _rate), false);
        }
        else
            sbmp = bmp;

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(w / 2, h / 2, (w < h ? w : h) / 2, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I use to implement a rounded image view with a colored border. Hope it helps you! http://pastebin.com/nbqhj12n

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps in order to help you :P

1- Create a drawable XML file inside your drawables folder specifying solid-color and radius.

2- Place an ImageView behind your RoundImageView higher than your ImageView dimensions.

3- Load the drawable into the new ImageView.